# webpack devserver proxy to https giving "Error occurred while trying to proxy request" and SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: webpack

Seeing Following error when trying to setup a proxy from localhost to http**s** site

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/analytics/getDataByPage from localhost:8080 to https://example.com:19502 (SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting, `secure: false` fixed the issue:

```
proxy: [
  {
    context: ["/api/**"],
    secure: false, // had an expression which was resolving to true
    changeOrigin: true,
  }
]
```

Comment: my target property was messed up.

was: `'target':'http://localhost/:3000/',`
should be: `'target': 'http://localhost:3000/',`

Comment: not solved problem for me

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error message. For me it worked by changing "**localhost**" to "**127.0.0.1**".

```
"/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:3456/",
    "secure": false
}
```

Comment: I had the same error while updating webpack 5.74.0 -> 5.82.0 (including webpack-cli 4.10.0 -> 5.1.0 respectively webpack-dev-server 4.9.3 -> 4.15.0) due to Kotlin 1.8 -> Kotlin 1.9 update

Comment: I think node will try to resolve ipv4 and ipv6 and ipv6 wins but your backend listens only on ipv4. Had that problem, too...

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue.
My API wasn't running as I was on too new a version of Node (18.*), changing to 16.* fixed it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33592262)

Comment: I had the same error, when looking for an answer through web searching I found this SO and others, but non fixed it. I'm leaving my answer as to help others in my same position.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same while running my Angular 17 App on dev mode.
The Webpack dev-server was throwing this HPM error:

```
[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api/v1/accounts/login/ to https://your.url.net/ [CERT_HAS_EXPIRED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

**Solution 1: Bypass SSL Certificate Validation Process on Dev mode.**

Setting the `secure: false` helps your dev-server, in my case; webpack bypass the SSL Certificate Verification process as below.

**src/proxy.conf.json**

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://your.url.net/",
    "secure": false, // Initially set to true for strict SSL validation
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

PS: This is only suitable & useful only for Local development, and it's important to have a valid SSL certificate in production for security reasons.

**Solution 2: Access Local Backend via IP address instead of http://localhost**

When the backend is running on localhost, consider changing the target link to access backend via IP Address e.g from localhost to http://127.0.0.1:8000/

```
"/api": {
    "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", //Initially set to 'http://localhost/'
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
}
```

PPS:

- Upvote if any of these suggested solved your problem.